# Change href link with php form

Tags: php, html, search, hyperlink, tags

I'm making a website with a search bar. I want to make the search bar interactive once it has "searched" and shown the results. So I want the href to chnage as per what Id is being used. For example: Someone searches "Pinecones", if its in the database it'll have an ID, for this example its #4. Once they searched it, it'll show up as a link. But I want the link to use "/#IDNumber.php"

This is the code im using:

```
<?php
$output = '';
//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `findgame` WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%'       OR keywords LIKE '%$searchq%' LIMIT 1") or die("Search unavailable.");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = 'Results not found.';

}else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $kwords = $row['keywords'];
        $id = $row['id'];

        $output .= '<div style="position:absolute;margin:110px    20px;padding:25px;">'.$id.' '.$name.'</div>';
        }

}

}

?>
```

and

```
<a href="/<?php$id?>.php">    <?php print("$output");?></a>
```

Any help in making it work?

Comment: Where's the code? I don't see anything but '.php">'

Answer (score 4):

You need to print the variable.

```
$id = 123;

<?php $id ?>      =>
<?php echo $id ?> => 123
<?= $id ?>        => 123
```

So the final result would be something like:

```
<a href="/<?= $id ?>.php">
    <?php print($output); ?>
</a>
```

Note: You don't need the `"` around `$output`. It won't hurt, but it's not necessary.

Comment: so it would be something like:   <a href="/<?php echo $id ?>.php"></a>

Comment: I don't get it.. Sorry bit of a noob at this

Comment: Basically change this: <a href="/<?php$id?>.php">    <?php print("$output");?></a> to this: <a href="/<?php echo $id ?>.php">    <?php print("$output");?></a> || You missed out "echo" before $id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what the problem is, for example I do not know whether you set $id and $output to any value.  I don't know if the context of the code you posted is within a PHP string, or if it is in a template.

However if it is just a question of syntax then the following may be better:

As a PHP string:

```
$out = '<a href="/' . $id . '">' . $output . '</a>';
```

An alternative:

```
$out = "<a href=\"/$id.php\">$output</a>";
```

In HTML:

```
<a href="/<?php print $id; ?>.php"><?php print $output; ?></a>
```

or even:

```
<?php print '<a href="/' . $id . '">' . $output . '</a>'; ?>
```

I hope that is all your problem was.

Note print and echo can be used interchangeably, people prefer print in this scenario although echo is slightly faster IIRC.  Neither of these are functions, so it is proper to NOT include parenthesis like print('blah').

Comment: just tried it... no it doesn't work... but i have edited the post above to give you a little more context

Comment: How does the first section of code relate to the 2nd?   Is the problem that the variables $id and $output are not present at the point of the second bit of code?
Do you get any error messages? Do you know how to check your error log?  It can be very helpful.

Comment: yes, i know how to check my error log. the first bit of code is a search engine. the second is the results engine.. don't worry.. i have fixed it now and it works